# lightdm Desktop icons File browsing is not Visible

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, lightdm

i have installed LightDM on my VPS along with x11VNC

with the Following commands

installing Lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

installing x11vnc

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

creating x11vnc service

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

service unit

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess -passwd password
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i am able to connect to my desktop successfully

but i am unable to see the desktop icons as example File Manager icon to check the files on machine etc..

any idea how to show the desktop icons ?

Comment: Do you have gnome-tweaks installed?

Comment: lightdm installed on freshly ubuntu installation

Comment: Does the problem persist with gdm3?